# How to normalize to integer values in Vector2 values?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I can't understand my question, too.
but help me.
I want `{1.5f , 4.5f} to {1 , 3}`
ex) `{0.5f , 2.5f} to {1 , 5}`
I want to change float to integer value.
Is there a useful function in this situation?

Comment: How does 4.5f turn into 3 and 2.5f into 5? What kind of math are you trying to perform?

Comment: I want to change all values to integer values.
(1.5 * 10 , 4.5 * 10) = (15 , 45)
(15 / 15 , 45 / 15)  = (1 , 3)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can multiply all your case with 1/(first case) like:

```
my_array = [1.5, 4.5, ...] 
coef = 1 / my_array[0] 
for i in range(1, len(my_array)): 
    my_array[i] = my_array[i] * coef
```

Answer (score 1):

In fact you do not want to normalize, you want to divide by x.

```cs
var vec = new Vector2(.5f, 1.5f);
vec /= vec.x;
Debug.Log(vec); // (1.0, 3.0)
```

Answer (score 0):

For your situation here,

You could always set your `X` to `1`, and then your `Y` value would become `Y / X`

this would only work when `X` is a factor of `Y` however.